# Rails 4: Trying to get an objects class name and running conditional code on the result

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, model

Consider the following code:

In my App, I have this:

```
   <div class="score"><%= model.class.name %></div>
```

which returns the class name `User`.

So why does:

```
       <% if model.class.to_s = "User" %>
```

in the following code:

```
  <div class="results">
    <% @search.each_hit_with_result do |hit, model| -%>
        <div class="result">
          <h2><%= hit.stored(:title) %></h2>
          <div class="score"><%= hit.score %></div>
          <div class="score"><%= model.class.name %></div>

                <% if model.class.to_s = "User" %>

                        Print this.....

                 <% end -%>
            <% end -%>
        </div>
     </div>
```

give:

```
       undefined method `to_s=' for #<Class:0x007f886b9c65a8>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `model.class.name` is already of `String`, `to_s` is not required. Meanwhile, your conditional should be

`<% if model.class.name == "User" %>`

Comment: I actually need to apologise for wasting your time. What a retarded error.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% if model.class.to_s = "User" %>
```

In the above code, You are using the assignment operator (`=`) instead of a comparison (`==`), that's not what you want. You should change that to:

```
<% if model.class.to_s == "User" %>
```

in such case, always try to debug to see what's in these inside the object. `inspect` is very handy in such cases. You could use:

```
puts model.inspect
puts model.class.inspect
```

These will give you more insights about the object's structure.

To explain the error you have got:

```
undefined method `to_s=' for #<Class:0x007f886b9c65a8>
```

You mistakenly used assignment operator which tried to call `to_s=` method on your class, but that's not implemented. That's why you got that `undefined method`to_s=` error.